# iMac 14,1 won't Netboot from Deploy Studio server running OS 10.8

Tags: osx-server, netboot

A little background, we have a lot of iMacs at my organization, different models.  We have about 5 different servers running Deploy Studio.

I have found that any of the 14,1 iMacs (late 2013) will only net boot to DS servers that are running OS 10.9+, if I attempt to net boot from a server running OS 10.8.5, using the same image that is hosted on the other servers, the unit will not net boot.  The unit stays at the Startup Manager for a few seconds, seemingly frozen, then Apple logo spinning gear, boots to login window of internal HD.

I have read that the TFTP protocol has changed, could this be the reason for the discrepancy of net booting from the same image on different Deploy Studio servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was eventually resolved.  We discovered that with Mavericks we could not netboot across subnets, which we previously had no issues with, so it seems to be unrelated to Deploy Studio or model.
Also learned that the TFTP protocol change is only relevant during netboot if you get the prohibited sign during boot, which we did not get.